# Draggable text box scales more than expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I made a text box and boxes on the corners for resizing. The first time I drag, it works perfectly fine, but after the 1st time, the dragging amount seems to multiply. (Don't mind the position of the dragging nodes). If you drag once, it scales fine with the mouse. It seems as if every time after that, when you drag, it scales farther and farther from the user's mouse, causing an 'uncontrollable' scale. I reset the values of the prevX and prevY values at the end of the move function. I'm not sure if that's the issue though. The issue, I believe, is with the scaling with getBoundingClientRect() in the resize portion. Moving the textbox, however, works perfectly fine. Here is my code:

```js
 var textBox = document.querySelector(".text-box");
            var textArea = document.querySelector('.text-field');
            textArea.focused = false;

            textBox.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

            let isResizing = false;
            let isTyping = false;

            textArea.addEventListener('dblclick', type)
            function type(){
                if (!isTyping){
                    isTyping = true;
                    textArea.style.cursor = 'text';
                }else {
                    isTyping = false;
                    textArea.style.cursor = 'default';
                }
            }

            document.body.onclick = function(e){
                if (e.target != textArea){
                isTyping = false;
                e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                }
            }

            function mousedown(e){
                if (e.target == textArea){
                    e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                }

                window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
                window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

                let prevX = e.clientX;
                let prevY = e.clientY;

                function mousemove(e){
                    if(!isResizing && !isTyping){
                    let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
                    let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

                    const rect = textBox.getBoundingClientRect();

                    textBox.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
                    textBox.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

                    prevX = e.clientX;
                    prevY = e.clientY;
                }
                }
                function mouseup(){
                    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
                    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
                }

                const handles = document.querySelectorAll('.handle');
                let currentHandle;

                for(let handle of handles){
                    handle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

                    function mousedown(e){
                        currentHandle = e.target;
                        isResizing = true;

                        let prevX = e.clientX;
                        let prevY = e.clientY;

                        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
                        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

                        function mousemove(e){
                            const rect = textBox.getBoundingClientRect();

                            if (currentHandle.classList.contains("se")) {
                                textBox.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                                textBox.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains("sw")) {
                                textBox.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                                textBox.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                                textBox.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains("ne")) {
                                textBox.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                                textBox.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                                textBox.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                            } else {
                                textBox.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                                textBox.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                                textBox.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                                textBox.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                            }
                            prevX = e.clientX;
                            prevY = e.clientY;
                        }

                        function mouseup(){
                            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
                            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
                            textArea.focused = false;
                            isResizing = false;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

```css
.text-box{
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .handle{
            position: absolute;
            width: 5px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: blue;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .ne{
            top: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            cursor: ne-resize;
        }
        .nw{
            top: -1px;
            left: -1px;
            cursor: nw-resize;
        }
        .sw{
            bottom: -1px;
            left: -1px;
            cursor: sw-resize;
        }
        .se{
            bottom: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            cursor: se-resize;
        }
        .text-field {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            resize: none;
            cursor: default;
        }
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
        <textarea class="text-field">Click to add text...</textarea>
        <div class="handle ne"></div>
        <div class="handle nw"></div>
        <div class="handle sw"></div>
        <div class="handle se"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your problem is that every time the text box mousedown event fires, you're adding a new mousedown event to each of the four handlers. Some of your code tries to clear out the handlers after they have run, but the ones on the handlers (`handle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);`) always get added and never get removed. Put a `console.log` into the internal `mousedown` event if you want to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just as Chris said on the comment, (However I tried many things before understanding the issue...)
One way very simple to solve it is to take out your for loop from inside your mousedown function.

```
var textBox = document.querySelector(".text-box");
var textArea = document.querySelector('.text-field');
textArea.focused = false;

textBox.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

let isResizing = false;
let isTyping = false;

textArea.addEventListener('dblclick', type)
function type(){
    if (!isTyping){
        isTyping = true;
        textArea.style.cursor = 'text';
    }else {
        isTyping = false;
        textArea.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}


document.body.onclick = function(e){
    if (e.target != textArea){
    isTyping = false;
    e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}

function mousedown(e){
    if (e.target == textArea){
        e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

    let prevX = e.clientX;
    let prevY = e.clientY;

    function mousemove(e){
        if(!isResizing && !isTyping){
        let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
        let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

        const rect = textBox.getBoundingClientRect();

        textBox.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
        textBox.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

        prevX = e.clientX;
        prevY = e.clientY;
    }
    }
    function mouseup(){
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
}

const handles = document.querySelectorAll('.handle');
let currentHandle;

for(let handle of handles){
    handle.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

    function mousedown(e){
        currentHandle = e.target;
        isResizing = true;

        let prevX = e.clientX;
        let prevY = e.clientY;

        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

        function mousemove(e){
            const rect = textBox.getBoundingClientRect();

            if (currentHandle.classList.contains("se")) {
                textBox.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                textBox.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains("sw")) {
                textBox.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                textBox.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                textBox.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains("ne")) {
                textBox.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                textBox.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                textBox.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else {
                textBox.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
                textBox.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                textBox.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
                textBox.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            }
            prevX = e.clientX;
            prevY = e.clientY;
        }

        function mouseup(){
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
            textArea.focused = false;
            isResizing = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Just one more thing, I added these lines to your code, to not remove the resize cursor when clicking the handler:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
     if (e.target != textArea){
         if(e.target.classList.contains('handle')){
             isTyping = false
         }
         else{
             isTyping = false;
             e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
         }
     }
 }
```